# Remix not connecting to testrpc

Tags: remix, testnets, testrpc, rpc

I am trying to deploy a smart contract on testrpc using External Http Provider which I have learnt has replace web3 provider. However when I try to run it. It says 'Error while connecting to the provider, provider not connected', but testrpc is running. and listening to localhost:8545. Which I should assume is the same that remix is trying to connect to although over https via 'https://127.0.0.1:8545'

Answer (score 0):

ok it seems I just needed to change the url provided by remix from 127.0.0.1:8545 to localhost:8545. I thought localhost and 127.0.0.1 functioned the same tho. I have tried using them interchangeably before. And the server still ran. Why exactly couldn't remix connect